# Trying to Build Grouped Bar Chart with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The issue I am having is how to correctly parse the csv data I have. The below are the columns I have within the csv file.

Program Title,Program Genre,Program Network,Viewer Hometown,Number of Viewers

I know I'm suppose to have this come through as an object but since the column names have spaces, they are making it harder when trying to create the grouped bar chart from other documentation I'm trying to follow.

How should I be going about this?

Comment: Do you use `d3.csv` (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js#d3.csv) ? If so, what is the problem you have with it?

Comment: If the doco you are following uses this kind of notation e.g. `data.column1` and for your data `column1` is 'Program Title' then you can use bracket notation e.g. `data["Program Title"]`